# How to pass a default parameter for std::shared_ptr<PureVirtualClass>

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, default-parameters

I have a function of type

```
virtual void foo(bla, bla, bla, std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> logger) = 0;
```

And I want to pass a default parameter with NULL pointer, something like:

```
virtual void foo(bla, bla, bla, std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> logger = NULL) = 0;
```

So that in implementation, if logger is `NULL` I do nothing with it, otherwise I use the logger.

I've tried to look for a solution but cannot find..

UPD: Duplicate claim is irrelevant, I am asking about default NULL parameter.

Is it possible that gcc 4.4 doesn't support nullptr?

Comment: You should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. The latter is a macro that is likely `0`, the former is the proper literal for a null pointer.

Comment: I've tried but also get compilation error:
 error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of "Can virtual functions have default parameters". The fact that the function is virtual is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @EricAbramov on linux u have to add -std=c++11

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do this:

```
virtual void foo(bla, bla, bla, std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> logger = {}) = 0;
```

As you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), both the empty constructor and `nullptr` give the same result, that is:

> Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty shared_ptr

Answer (score 3):

**With a C++11 compliant compiler**

This should work with either `NULL` or `nullptr` the latter being the recommended form for C++.  The only condition is that you compile it for c++11 or higher (see comment of jamek about the command line options for gcc).

```
struct B {
    virtual void foo(int blablabla, std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> logger = nullptr) = 0;
};

struct D : B {
    void foo(int blablabla, std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> logger) override {
        std::cout << "foo: "<<blablabla<<" "<< logger<<std::endl; 
    }
};

int main() {
    D d; 
    B *b=&d;
    b->foo(15); 
}
```

See [online demo](http://ideone.com/Ksjhvi)

**Important remark about default parameters**

Note that the default parameter is not intrinsic to the function itself, but to the context in which the default value was declared.  In the example above:

- `b->foo(15)` works, because the function is accessed using the `B` class for which a default parameter is defined.
- `d.foo(15)` won't even compile, despite both referring to the same function.  This is  because for the `D` class I didn't declare a default value in the definition of the override.
- I could even have a different default value for both definitions (see in the online demo)

**Limitated implementation of C++11 in GCC 4.4**

Indeed, `nullptr` was introduced with GCC 4.6 and you have to wait GCC 4.8.1 for a [full C++11 implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11).

In fact GCC 4.4.0 was [released in 2009](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/) and the first sub-release after the official approval of the standard in [august 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) was GCC 4.4.7.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is that gcc 4.4 doesn't support all c++11 features like nullptr

Comment: [Indeed](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11): nullptr was introduced only with 4.6 !

Comment: @EricAbramov and And [4.4.0 dates back to 2009](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/), and 4.4.7 was the first release after the official approval of [c++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

Comment: Yeah, I  should wait until the production pipeline in my company will be upgraded to gcc 4.6

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you are looking to pass a null pointer, then do not use shared_ptr as the argument type. 
Instead use a raw pointer. This way, you don't have to figure out the arcane default value for a shared pointer.

And you can keep the benefits of shared_ptr by passing the embedded raw pointer. In your case, it looks like below.

```
// In declaration file
virtual void foo(bla, bla, bla, LoggerInterface* logger = nullptr) = 0;
```

```
std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> loggerPtr(new LoggerInterface());
// or
std::shared_ptr<LoggerInterface> loggerPtr;

// Call the function
Bar bar;
bar.foo(bla, bla, bla, loggerPtr ? loggerPtr.get() : nullptr);
...
```